# Can't build Swift app including Objective-C Tesseract library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, compiler-errors, tesseract

I am trying to utilize the features of Tesseract OCR for an iOS app, and cannot even seem to get it going. I have followed the installation instructions to the tee and have still been unable to get it built correctly.

I have used CocoaPods to integrate Tesseract into my project, and that seems to be working fine, but, I am unsure of exactly what to put into my bridging header. There are over 50 header files in the Tesseract portion of the project, and it doesn't seem like I should need to add each individually into the bridging header.

With copy and pasting the basic code from the instructions into my project, I get a few errors:

1) /Users/kade/Documents/tesseract/tesseract/ViewController.swift:19:30:

> Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'G8TesseractDelegate'

corresponds with this line of code:

```
tesseract.delegate = self;
```

2) if I comment this line out, the build succeeds, but then breaks upon execution of the following line:

```
tesseract.charWhitelist = "01234567890";
```

I believe this to be a bridging header issue because I have imported a file and fixed a previous error, but I'm not sure which Objective-C header file will include all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake, I just figured it out.

I needed to include: ", G8TesseractDelegate" at the class declaration.

Silly me!

I hope this helps anyone who may be experiencing something similar! :)